# Android build tool command aapt “cannot execute binary file”

Tags: executable, file-format

I have build tools version 25.0.1 installed on a machine running Enterprise Red Hat Linux, 64 bit.  When I try and run the aapt command, from the command line I get the following:

```
-bash: ./aapt: cannot execute binary file
```

From researching it looks like the issue is that the aapt executable was compiled for 32 bit.  I have tried many suggestions out there to install via yum libs to allow 32 bit executables to run, but none have let aapt run.

Here is the output from `file ./aapt`

```
./aapt: Mach-O 64-bit executable
```

Here is the output from the uname command

```
3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 11:24:13 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does `sudo rpm -q --file ./appt` output? Also this maybe be useful to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O

Comment: file /ci/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.1/aapt is not owned by any package

Thank you! I manually copied the sdk to the server btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./appt` is not a ELF formatted executable, it's a [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) executable. This format is used on macOS, so evidently you have a macOS executable, not a Linux executable. What does `sudo rpm -q --file ./appt` output?

You might what to see if there is a version of `./appt` available to your system by executing: `sudo yum --enablerepos=* provides '*/appt'`

Comment: It could be that the system I download the original files on was OSX.  Thank you for the Mach-O suggestion, investigating further.